# Time step computation in Matlab ODE solver

Tags: matlab, ode

I tried to find out how MATLAB computes the step size (not the initial one) to solve ODEs with, for example, the `ode45` solver. The source code is really complex, so does anyone know hot it works?

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that the step size is dynamically adapted, there no "The" step size.

---

To get a general simplified idea: The total error E is composed of the atomic errors of every time step. In first order it is summation, more exactly there is some kind of cumulative magnification of the atomic errors involved.

A sensible approach would be that every time step of length h should have an atomic error of about E·h/T, where T is the length of the integration interval. The order 4 method has an local error of C·h^5 where C is in zeroth order a polynomial in the first 4 derivatives of the ODE function. Since the method computes an order 4 and an order 5 step, call them y4 and y5, one can take y5 as the more precise one so that approximately C·h^5 = |y4-y5|. This allows to compute C and to adapt the step size a·h to get the desired atomic error, since one can solve C·(a·h)^5=E/T·(a·h) to get

```
a = pow( E/T·h/norm(y4-y5), 1/4)
```

This does not need to be terribly exact, so that one can just use the adapted step size for the next step if the atomic error is not largely out of range.

Another approach is to compare if the local error |y4-y5|/h falls inside a bracket around the desired local error E/T and increase/decrease the step size by a constant factor, with a repetition of the step if the step size needed to be reduced.

There is more to the advanced/actual implementations, taking into account relative and absolute error goals, detecting stiffness, i.e., where the local error formula breaks down, …

Comment: I am sorry I do not get what you want to explain. Could you please explain it maybe in more easy words?